# Generating heap dump from docker container running in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, hazelcast, heap-dump

We are using hazelcast-enterprise:4.1.1 docker image and deployed three nodes in kubernetes cluster, how to generate the heap dumps or thread dumps from these servers running in a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using enterprise version, you should submit a support ticket with Hazelcast team.